# Word Count logic

Tags: c, enums, logic

So for an intro to C class we have to write a program that will count the number of lines, characters, and words in a file. In the program a word is defined as a sequence of letters, digits, and apostrophes that begins with a letter. For some reason the logic for counting words just isn't working for me, maybe it's because I'm new to C or because I've always been bad at formulating logic. My code now, when passed in
`hey whats up\n
       hey what's up\n
       hey wh?ts 'p\n`
returns 3 lines, 31 words, 40 characters. Thanks for any help, I know this is a super lame question it's just driving me insane.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum yesno yesno;
enum yesno {
    YES,
    NO
};

int main() {
    int c;          // character
    int nl, nw, nc; // number of lines, words, characters
    yesno inword;   // records if we are in a word or not
    yesno badchar;
    // initialize variables:
    badchar=NO;
    inword = NO;
    nl     = 0;
    nw     = 0;
    nc     = 0;`

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            inword = NO;
        else if (inword == NO) {
            inword = YES;
        }
        while (inword == YES){
            if (( c<'A' || c>'Z')||(c<'a'||c>'z')||(c<'0'|| c>'9') ){
                inword= NO;
                //badchar = YES;
            }
            if (( c<'A' || c>'Z')||(c<'a'||c>'z')|| (c<'0'|| c>'9') ||(c!=  '\'')){
                nw=nw;
                inword = NO;
                //badchar=YES;
            }
            if(badchar==NO){
                nw++;
                badchar=NO;
                inword= NO;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation/formatting? Your code is very difficult to read as it is currently.

Comment: I would like to but for some reasons the method for inputting code on my computer seems to be very clumsy. I basically just paste the code in and then go down each line pressing [space] four times.

Comment: The word count problem is that you increment word count every time you consume another letter in a word. You need to only increase it when you change from in a word to out of a word.

Comment: I've realized that for some reason, just turning on the `badchar` variable to `NO` results in an infinite loop

Comment: Does the program work without the badchar code? What I mean is with any nonspacing character able to make a word, does it output the correct number of words? If not, I'd worry less about the badchar stuff and focus on figuring out how to count words in the first place. The badchar code should be easy enough after that.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is this condition:

```
if (( c<'A' || c>'Z')||(c<'a'||c>'z')||(c<'0'|| c>'9') ){
    inword = NO;
```

Consider a value of `c` such as:

- `'A'`: this is going to be less than `'a'`, so you'll switch to `inword = NO`.
- `'a'`: this is going to be greater than `'Z'`, so you'll switch to `inword = NO`.
- `'0'`: this is going to be less than `'A'`, so you'll switch to `inword = NO`.

You need to use `&&` between the sets of conditions:

```
if ((c < 'A' || c > 'Z') && (c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < '0' || c > '9')){
```

Or, better, you could use the macros/functions from `<ctype.h>`:

```
if (!isupper(c) && !islower(c) && !isdigit(c))
```

but that can be abbreviated to:

```
if (!isalnum(c))
```

You'll need to review the other tests too.  There could be other problems too, but I've simply not reviewed the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never programmed C. But when I've programmed this same thing in other languages, it's not too tough. For word count, replace "\n" with space, then split the string into an array using a space as the delimiter, and finally count the number of elements in the array.  Similar thing to get the line count: split the string into an array using "\n" as the delimiters, then count the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't declare arrays just yet in C, it's not as simple as in java, and making it space delimited would also be similarly tricky for me at this point in our c class.